# Is Dataset#persist() a terminal operation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Does spark actually cache the `Dataset` when `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset#persist()` is called? Or it will be cached lazily when some terminal operation (like `count`) will be called on a `Dataset`.

Answer (score 2):

As all caching operations in Spark `Dataset.persist` is lazy and only marks given object for caching, if it is ever evaluated.

The main difference compared to RDDs is that the evaluation is much harder to reason about. See related discussion on the developers list: [Will .count() always trigger an evaluation of each row?](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Will-count-always-trigger-an-evaluation-of-each-row-td21018.html)